# How to set visible=true when a component is selected in the structure panel?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I would like to change the property visible of a component when I select it in the **structure panel**. I know for example that when I select a component in the structure panel then the parent of my component will receive 2 new objects (to draw the selection, maybe), `TGrabHandle.TGrabHandleEllipse` and `TDesignRectangle`

So I can detect that I select a component in the structure panel by overriding the `DoAddObject` procedure of the parent of my control like this :

```
procedure TMyControl.DoAddObject(const AObject: TFmxObject);
begin
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) and
     (AObject.ClassNameIs('TGrabHandle.TGrabHandleEllipse')) or
     (AObject.ClassNameIs('TDesignRectangle')) then begin
     ....
  end
end;
```

But all of this seems to be a little complicated and I would like to know if there is a better way to know (at design time) when a component is selected in the structure panel?

Comment: Can you be more specific? In what context do you need to detect the selection? Do you need for your control to detect when *it* has been selected, or do you need your control to detect when one of its *children* had been selected? Do you need to distinguish between selection in the structure panel versus selection in the Form Designer?

Comment: I need it to detect when the control has been selected. I don't really need to distinguish between selection in the structure panel versus selection in the form designer because i overrided the GetObjectAtPoint of my control and now it's not possible to select it anymore in the form designer (only in the structure panel)

Comment: I see. You've dug yourself into a hole, and you're asking how to make the hole more comfortable. Maybe you can just not dig so deeply in the first place: Have you considered only overriding `ObjectAtPoint` when *not* in design mode?

Comment: maybe you are right :( i think now i m just in a hole and would like to goo more deeply :( i was just curious if their is no any "official" or "supported" way to do it, but i start to be sure, no :(